# When adding the AMPSCRIPT "InsetData" function in my Cloud Page, it get an error 500

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm having problems on an unsubscribe page when i add an insertDATA function. The page is working well without this function.

SO i try to insert "SubscriberID" (Data type is texte 50 length, and it's the Primary key) and "rm_optin_c" = false (data type is Boolean, nullable is true and default value is "false") into the DE "DE_TAMPON_Unsub_Pref_Page".

The code that makes the Cloudpage error is this one :

```
Set @optintampon = 'false'
set @insertoptin = insertData("DE_TAMPON_Unsub_Pref_Page", "rm_optin_c", @optintampon, "SubscriberID", @subkey)
```

The AMP for the entire Cloudpage is

```
  set @subkey = _subscriberKey
  set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
  set @brandnlspecialoccasion = IIF(RequestParameter("brandnlspecialoccasion")=='on','true','false')
  set @cocktailinspiration = IIF(RequestParameter("cocktailinspiration")=='on','true','false')
  set @distillerynews = IIF(RequestParameter("distillerynews")=='on','true','false')
 
 
 
 
 
  IF (@brandnlspecialoccasion == 'false' AND @cocktailinspiration == 'false' and @distillerynews == 'false') then
  set @version = 'A'
  
  

  
    set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
                             "Contact", @subkey,
                             "Newsletter_subscription_Brand_News_Sp__c", @brandnlspecialoccasion,
                             "NewsletterSubscriptionCocktailInspirat__c", @cocktailinspiration,
                             "Newsletter_subscription_Dystillerie__c", @distillerynews,
                             "rm_OptIn__c","false"
                        );
 
 Set @optintampon = 'false'

set @insertoptin = insertData("DE_TAMPON_Unsub_Pref_Page", "rm_optin_c", @optintampon, "SubscriberID", @subkey)


  else
  set @version = 'B'
   set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
                             "Contact", @subkey,
                             "Newsletter_subscription_Brand_News_Sp__c", @brandnlspecialoccasion,
                             "NewsletterSubscriptionCocktailInspirat__c", @cocktailinspiration,
                             "Newsletter_subscription_Dystillerie__c", @distillerynews                          
                        );
  ENDIF
  
  
 IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN
  set @optinglobal = IIF(RequestParameter("Email_Opt_in")=='on','true','false')
  IF @optinglobal == 'true' THEN
  set @updateRecord2 = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
                             "Contact", @subkey,                          
                             "rm_OptIn__c","true"
                        );
                        
                       ENDIF
                       ENDIF

 ]%%
```

Does anyone know why adding the insertData line makes the whole Page an error 500 ?

Comment: Could you try wrapping your code into an SSJS `try... catch` statement? That could potentially return the error. Other than that, does a record for this particular SubscriberID already exist in the DE? You could potentially try changing the function from `InsertData` to `UpsertData` to avoid a primary key violation error.

Comment: I'm not sure, because the problem appears when i try to publish the page, it's instantly in error 500. My problem is not the data i try to put into the DE, but to publish the Cloud Page. The DE is empty so it shouldn't have problem of PK violation. And i already tryed to use UpsertData, but unfortunatly it doesnt change anything.

Comment: The `rm_optin_c` is of the Boolean data type in the data extension? Currently you set the value as `'false'` which is a string, maybe try one of these: `Set @optintampon = false` or `Set @optintampon = 0`

Comment: Yes `rm_optin_` is Boolean data type in the DE. i tryed to set `@optintampon` to `false or 0 ` but it still tells me that i cannot publish the cloud page

Comment: Maybe post a screen of what you seen when you try to publish, but you should be able to save and publish the page regardless of the errors shown in the preview. Can you try to do that? Preview should fail here anyway since it does not have access to any personalization strings like `_subscriberkey`.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to post a screen shot, but here is what's written : `An error occurred while previewing this content.

This can happen for many reasons, including incomplete or incorrect MC scripting (AMPscript, SSJS or GTL) or missing subscriber context.

Click Cancel to review your code or Publish to push the updated content live.`  I can publish it yes, but when i go to the URL, it gives an error 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is due to lack of proper data validation prior to firing your *insertData()* function. It expects a value in *@subkey* variable. This is set in this statement in the top of your code: `set @subkey = _subscriberKey`. However, when the Cloud Page is just viewed, and not accessed via *CloudPagesUrl()* function, *_subscriberKey* is not available, resulting in *@subkey* being set to null.

This means, that this CloudPage could theoretically work, when following a link from an email. To prevent the error from occurring, I would recommend you to check whether or not *@subkey* is actually set to something meaningful:

```ampscript
IF NOT EMPTY(@subkey) THEN
SET @insertoptin = insertData("DE_TAMPON_Unsub_Pref_Page", "rm_optin_c", @optintampon, "SubscriberID", @subkey)
ENDIF
```

A natural question would be:

> But Lukas, I also use *@subkey* in my *UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()* function. Why doesn't this fail as well?

Well, *UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()* simply returns 0 if the update wasn't successful. While *insertData()* throws an error, in a very non-elegant way.

Comment: Thanks so much Lukas, it worked !!

Comment: You’re welcome!